# Single JetBrains Hub for YouTrack and Upsource

Tags: youtrack, upsource

I have already set YouTrack and there's also hub for auth,..

I'm setting up Upsource now and it has its own hub, is there a way I can use single hub for upsource and youtrack?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first Upsource release isn't intended to be used with the Hub, provided with YouTrack. This is definitely abnormal state of the art, which will be addressed in the next minor update (approx Q2'15).